# OpenID with Authlogic openid-selector and yahoo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid

I've got registering/logging in working with at least Google and myOpenID with I thought should represent the two methods of passing parameters back from the provider but I'm not able to get an email or nickname back from Yahoo. I get passed to Yahoo's verification page but when I allow params aren't getting passed to my site.

Here's my User model code. Everything else is just stock Authlogic except the front-end uses the openid-selector jquery plugin.

http://pastie.org/649912

I've tried putting :email and :nickname in the required_fields array but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [these](http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/index.php?s=d8db21829e9f4e153c26876e3a9b9bb9&showtopic=1331) [threads](http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/index.php?s=d8db21829e9f4e153c26876e3a9b9bb9&showtopic=295) it is not yet supported by Yahoo.